# Cache mediator not returning cached response in EI 6.1

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm trying to add a cache functionality to my service exposed as an API, so that repeated requests would get a cached response. But instead of the cached response, the mediator is returning me the message sent by the client.
Here follows the configuration of my api.It describes a get resource that receives two query parameters and uses them to create a payoad, which it sends to a local dss service:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/config" name="myAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET">
        <inSequence>
            <cache collector="false" hashGenerator="org.wso2.carbon.mediator.cache.digest.DOMHASHGenerator" id="testCache" scope="per-mediator" timeout="200">
                <onCacheHit/>
                <implementation maxSize="100" type="memory"/>
            </cache>
            <property expression="$url:intg" name="uri.integration" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="$url:inst" name="uri.institution" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <con:show xmlns:con="http://com.dvg.wso2/configservice">
                        <con:SEL_INTG_NAME>$1</con:SEL_INTG_NAME>
                        <con:SEL_INSTITUTION>$2</con:SEL_INSTITUTION>
                    </con:show>
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('uri.integration')"/>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('uri.institution')"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <header name="Action" scope="default" value="urn:show"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                    <address format="soap11" uri="local:///services/INTG_DVG_ConfigService/"/>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <cache collector="true" scope="per-mediator" id="testCache"/>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

My expected output should be something like this:

```
<soapenv:Body>
    <properties>
        <property>
          <key>A</key>
          <value>A</value>
        </property>
    </properties>
</soapenv:Body>
```

But I'm receiving a cached response like this:

```
<con:show xmlns:con="http://com.dvg.wso2/configservice"><con:SEL_INTG_NAME>A</con:SEL_INTG_NAME><con:SEL_INSTITUTION>A</con:SEL_INSTITUTION></con:show>
```

Which is the content of the payload I'm creating in my in sequence. It should be stated that I receive the expected response in the case of a cache miss.

Shouldn't the cache mediator, configured as it is, store the response of the cache miss and return it in case of cache hit?
Why is it responding with the wrong content?

--- Edit ---
After changing the configuration for the org.wso2.carbon.mediator.cache.CacheMediator log, I was able to conirm that the cache mediator is indeed saving and restoring the input message instead of the response.
This behavior does not occurs if I try to reproduce it in a proxyService, only in an API.

Comment: Might be becouse of cache-type is your case is finder (It cache incoming message not a response)

Comment: @simar Don't we need a pair of collector/finder mediators for the cache to work? One to search for the request hash of incoming messages and another to collect the response messages in the cache?

Comment: You are right.I didn't pay attention reading documentation.

Comment: Easiest way to debug might be to override onCacheHit and append custom http header, something like 'Cache-Hit: true'. This will help to ensure that you receive message from cache and that correct message was places into it previously.

Comment: Make sure timeout is enough between requests

Comment: Last payloadFactory mediator is not clear what for. It inject body into body of message with body tag with contains body of received message.

Comment: You can get message content using xpath expression $body/*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to get the cache mediator to work in the api, but I observed that it behaved as expected when implemented in a proxy service.
So I ended up refactoring my integration so that the api would call a proxy service, and then this proxy would verify the cache before calling the dss service.
Since the call to the proxy and the dss use local transport, there was not a big impact on the performance.
If someone is reading this in the future, and have some insight on how to properly use the cache mediator on a api service, please leave a comment.